# How to add TooTip to MenuItem

Tags: wpf, menu, tooltip, menuitem

This is my Menu:

```
<Menu Name="menuInterfaces" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Margin="0,8,0,0" Style="{StaticResource StandardMenu}">
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Menu:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

And my `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}" x:Key="StandardMenu">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="Separator">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource ApplicationFontSize}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <!--Border 1-->
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"  CornerRadius="2"
                                    BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="HeaderHost" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Margin="8,1,8,1" x:Name="IGTHost" ContentSource="InputGestureText" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           Placement="Right"
                                           HorizontalOffset="-1" 
                                           x:Name="SubMenuPopup"
                                           Focusable="false"
                                           PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                                           AllowsTransparency="True">
                                        <Grid Margin="0,0,5,5">
                                            <!--Border 2-->
                                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" CornerRadius="5"
                                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorBorderBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                                    Background="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}" 
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Margin="2">
                                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Border.Effect>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Color="Black"/>
                                                </Border.Effect>
                                            </Border>
                                            <!--Border 3-->
                                            <Border Margin="1,0,0,0"
                                                    x:Name="TransitionBorder"
                                                    Width="0" 
                                                    Height="2" 
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                    Background="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Popup>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,6,2"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="SubMenuBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="SubMenu" Property="Margin" Value="2,3,2,2"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="TransitionBorder" Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,6,2"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,0,3"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,0,3"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                        <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemHighlightedBackground}"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                        <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemHighlightedBackground}"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                        <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                        <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true"/>
                                        <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#55B3B3B6"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#55B3B3B6"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>

                                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>

                                <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
                                    --><!--<Setter Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="False"/>-->
                                    <!--<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>--><!--
                                </Trigger>-->
                                <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    --><!--<Setter Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>--><!--
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanelPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
                                </Trigger>-->

                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="False"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiTrigger>

                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="False"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#55B3B3B6"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiTrigger>

                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#55B3B3B6"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiTrigger>

                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#55B3B3B6"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiTrigger>

                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsManagement}" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MenuDisabledForeground}"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>

                                <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MenuDisabledForeground}"/>
                                </Trigger>-->

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
    </Style>
```

View model:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly ICommand _command;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public bool _isSelected { get; set; }

        public MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            _command = new CommandViewModel(Execute);
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return _command; }
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            // (NOTE: In a view model, you normally should not use 
        }
    }
```

Now all i want to do is add `ToolTip` so under `Menu` section inside my `XAML` i added this section:

```
<Menu.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </ToolTip>
</Menu.ToolTip>
```

But nothings is shown so my suspicion is my `Style` but i cant find out where..

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your bindings it seems to me your intention is to add the tooltip to the individual menu items rather than the top-level menu itself, so you probably want to be doing something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- etc -->

</Style>
```